# How to spell TCP IP

Tags: networking, tcp

I am a bit confused as how we name / spell / write TCP/IP protocol. Actually I am building a library around the same and wanted to know the correct library name I should give. I am unsure which letters should be in CAPITAL and which should in small characters and why like:

```
TCP_IP
Tcp_Ip
Tcp_IP
TCP_ip
tcpip
tcp_ip
TcpIp
```

Is there a naming convention for TCP/IP protocol with regards to others - when should IP or TCP be in CAPITAL and do they have special meaning like Ethernet/IP why the IP is written in capital?

Comment: TCP (Transmission Control Protocol) is a protocol, IP (Internet Protocol) is a protocol, ethernet (IEEE 802.3) is a set of protocols. TCP and IP are acronyms that should be capitalized, and they are really separate protocols at separate network layers (there is actually an RFC for TCP over IPX - Internetwork Packet Exchange). Ethernet was created by Bob Metcalfe, who argued against capitalizing it, although most people do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP is an abbreviation of Internet Protocol this is cause of capital IP. 
Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol for more information about TCP